# Find the normal vector to a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

If we have the equation $2x+2y+8z=2$, how do we find the normal vector?
My thinking is you do $2^2+2^2+8^2$ and then square root the number.

Comment: The normal vector is $(2,2,8)$ , its length is $\sqrt{2^2+2^2+8^2}$ which is what you did.

Comment: so the normal vector to the plane is just (2,2,8)?

Comment: Yes, it is actually that easy.

Comment: Yes, just in case, remember you can only use this idea for planes and not general surfaces.

Comment: Yes, and divide the components by the length to get a unit vector (of length 1)

Comment: thank you, makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can always remember that, given a plane, it can be represented by the expression
$$ax+by+cz+d=0,$$
for certain values of $a,b,c,d$. If you have the plane (just valid for planes, not general surfaces) expressed like this, the normal vector is just $(a,b,c)$ divided by its norm (to make it of lenght 1, but just $(a,b,c)$ works if what you want is its direction).

Notice this is true since parameterizing the directions of the vectors of the plane by doing $x=t$, $y=s$, we then have that the direction of the $z$ axis is $\frac{-at-bs}{c}$ (the value of $d$ does not affect the direction of the vectors of the plane). So then it's easily seen that
$$\left\langle (a,b,c),\left(t,s,\frac{-at-bs}{c}\right) \right\rangle=at+bs-at-bs=0.$$